# What are the options to benchmark different versions of your code (to avoid bloat and performance decreases)?

Tags: c++, performance, continuous-integration, performance-testing

What are the options to benchmarking different build versions against each other to measure performance over time?

Ideally it is something which can be implemented into a CI pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you could use

```
time yourProgram
```

giving user, real and sys timings.

Or use

perf

where you can get various timings of performance.